# Invalid Paypal payment confirmation response

Tags: php, paypal, cakephp-3.0

I need to know why Paypal giving "invalid status" when making handshake to confirm payment. while payment is receiving and everything is good.

Following code is for send request to make payment.

```
$path = "http:/127.0.0.1/acedmy/";
$paypal_email = 'imranguher-seller@hotmail.com';
$return_url = $path .'Packages/success';
$cancel_url = $path .'Packages/cancel';
$notify_url = $path .'Packages/success';

$item = $this->request->data["item_number"];
$itemArray = explode("_", $item);

$payer_email = "imranguher-buy@hotmail.com";

$querystring = '';
$querystring .= "?cmd=".urlencode("_xclick"). "&";
$querystring .= "business=".urlencode($paypal_email). "&";
$querystring .= "payer_email".urlencode($payer_email). "&";
$querystring .= 'currency_code='. urlencode( 'USD'). "&";
$querystring .= "item_name=".urlencode(stripslashes("monthly")). "&";
$querystring .= "amount="."20". "&";
$querystring .= "item_number="."121"."&";
$querystring .= "submit_x=".urlencode(stripslashes($this->request->data['submit_x'])). "&";
$querystring .= "submit_y=".urlencode(stripslashes($this->request->data['submit_y'])). "&";
$querystring .= "return=".urlencode(stripslashes($return_url)). "&";
$querystring .= "cancel_return=".urlencode(stripslashes($cancel_url)). "&";        
$querystring .= "notify_url=".urlencode($notify_url);


header('location:https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr'.$querystring);      
        exit();
```

Code to confirm if payment is successful and valid .

```
  $req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
foreach ($_GET as $key => $value) {
$value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
$req .= "&$key=$value";
}

debug($req);
// post back to PayPal system to validate
$header = "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.0\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($req) . "\r\n\r\n";


$fp = fsockopen ('ssl://www.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);
 if (!$fp) {
// HTTP ERROR
} else {
fputs ($fp, $header . $req);
while (!feof($fp)) {
$res = fgets ($fp, 1024);
if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {

 $status = "verified";
 debug($status);
// PAYMENT VALIDATED & VERIFIED!

}
else if (strcmp ($res, "INVALID") == 0) {

  $status = "Invalid";
 debug($status);
// PAYMENT INVALID & INVESTIGATE MANUALY!

}
}
fclose ($fp);
}
```

After debugging response I get following

```
\src\Controller\PackagesController.php (line 168)
'cmd=_notify-validate&tx=6JS3234156861063R&st=Completed&amt=5.00&cc=USD&cm=&item_number=3_1'
\src\Controller\PackagesController.php (line 192)
'Invalid'
```

payment was successful but still giving error.